# Adding values into ArrayList

Tags: java

I am working on creating a program for sorting a list of names read in by a file. The problem I am encountering is, the teacher wants us to open a file and add in all of the values (each line is a value) into an ArrayList. It would be easy to add in all of the values from the file into an ArrayList, but the teacher requires that it be of type Name, which is a separate class in the package. What do I need to have in my Name class to allow for the following code to work-

```
String line = null;
    ArrayList<Name> nameAL = new ArrayList<>();
     try {
        FileReader fileReader = 
            new FileReader(fileName);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            nameAL.add(line);
        }   
        bufferedReader.close();
        if (nameAL.size() <= 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File invalid", "Input Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println("File must have at least one element");
        }               

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" + 
            fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file, must have at least one element '" 
            + fileName + "'");                  
    }
    return nameAL;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question ?

Comment: It sounds like you need to import your `Name` class. `import package.path.to.Name` at the top of your file that wants to use it.

Comment: The import is not necessary because it's in the same package, the error I'm getting from the line    nameAL.add(line) is that the string "line" cannot be converted to Name

Comment: You cannot add line to an `ArrayList` of type `Name`, instead you need to create a `Name` object for every line on the fly while you're reading the file and use a setter method (should be in the Name Class)  to add the Line to a String field in the `Name` Class (Suppose you have it already)

Comment: You need to call the constructor of the class `Name`... example: `nameAll( new Name(line) );` ... here, I'm assuming that your Name class have a constructor with a signature like this: `public Name(String value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. A name class would look something like

```
public Class Name{
    private String name;

    public Name(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    ...getters and setters....
}
```

When adding a new line (which I assume is a name) then

```
  nameAL.add(new Name(line));
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<Name>` means the list should contain instances of Name. You need to accept a string argument in your name class and store an instantiation of it in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the constructors of Name class. Then fix this line:

```
nameAL.add(line);
```

into

```
nameAL.add(new Name(...));
```

You should add your line as a Name instance into `ArrayList<Name> nameAL`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you do this:
bufferedReader.readLine() you are getting a String value.

You need to transform that String value into a Name class.

All you need to do is create a new Name instance using the Name constructor that will read the String value, like this:

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
  nameAL.add(new Name(line));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create *Name* class in the current package as below.

```
class Name{
private String name;

 public void setName(String name){
   this.name = name;
 }

 public String getName(){
   return name;
 }
}
```

and change the below code in **while** loop

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        Name name = new Name();
        name.setName(line);
        nameAL.add(name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a Class `Name` like this (for example):

```
public class Name {
    String name; // this field to contain the name

    // the constructor
    public Name(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    // a getter and a setter
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Now you can add the line read every time via Creating a new `Object` of `Name` for every line, something like this:

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    nameAL.add(new Name(line)); // this called anonymous Object of class
}
```

Then you can read the lines back from the `ArrayList` like this (for example):

```
for(Name name : nameAL){
    System.out.println(name.getName);
}
```